# Fun topic for undergraduate seminar

Tags: education, big-list

I have already asked myself (and been asked) a couple of times what would be possible topics for undergraduate seminars. In such a seminar students are given passages of a book (or even paper) which they have to present to their fellow students.

As an analysist I sometimes feel that the topics get very advanced quickly, making it hard to include second year students (that have seen pointset topology, calculus, measure theory, a bit of abstract algebra and an intro to numerics). The one time I run a seminar, I picked Devaney's book "An introduction to chaotic dynamical systems", which gives a down-to-earth intro to chaotic systems and does not use much, still is a very fun topic also interesting for more advanced students. My question would be:

> Do you know other such "easy" (not many prerequisites) and "non-technical" topics that would be suitable for an undergraduate seminar?

I am not sure this is a suitable question as it quite open and has no definitive answer. If you feel I should change it in some way or ask it somewhere else, please let me know (I mostly answer questions and have not asked many so far).

Comment: [This journal](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/expositiones-mathematicae) has more exposition style papers, which lend themselves well to seminars.

Comment: @DonThousand You must have very talented undergraduates :) I quickly browsed through some of the articles and they seems fun to me, but I don't think average undergraduates could cope with that. Maybe I am too pessimistic.

Comment: Combinatorics might be a rich area for what you suggest. E.g. the many different ways you can prove Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem and its many equivalent forms. From there, maybe the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem with its many proofs and forms. I'm currently collecting various proofs of the Jordan Curve Theorem and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. Check out Proofs from the Book and Bollobas' The Art of Mathematics, I'm sure the results there will give you many ideas.

Comment: Oh, also check out winning articles of the Paul R. Halmos and the Lester R. Ford Awards for ideas.

Comment: @Teddy38 Thanks for the suggestion! That sounds quite nice. Have much of the rather heavy machinery of algebraic topology would one need to show the Brower fixed point theorem?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven There are proofs which don't use algebraic topology at all. In "Proofs form the Book" they show you how to prove it (only the 2d version, but it generalises) using Sperner's Lemma and passing from discrete to continuous. A full proof can be found in Bollobas' "Linear Analysis".

Comment: @Teddy38 Ohh, now I am really curious. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: And my favourite, you can prove it using the fact that the game of Hex will never draw: http://www.math.pitt.edu/~gartside/hex_Browuer.pdf

Comment: @Teddy38 That is a real gem!

Comment: Related: [Short papers for undergraduate course on reading scholarly math](https://mathoverflow.net/q/295696/15780) *AND* [Readings for an honors liberal art math course](https://mathoverflow.net/q/88946/15780). Besides looking at past issues of various MAA journals, see past issues of [**Pi Mu Epsilon Journal**](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/issues.html) *AND* [**The Pentagon**](https://www.kappamuepsilon.org/pentagon.html) *AND* [**Mathematical Spectrum**](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1xPIYMkLAZgc-M6Pdj0vBFrHEOnLsifH3) **(continued)**

Comment: *AND* [**Quantum**](https://www.nsta.org/quantum-magazine-math-and-science) *AND* [**Involve**](https://msp.org/involve/2022/15-1/index.xhtml).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that arithmetic billiards can fit your requirements. Wikipedia has the article [Arithmetic billiards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_billiards) and Wolfram MathWorld has the article [Billiards](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Billiards.html).

Comment: I know this topic from my reading of the Spanish article *El billar como computador analógico* by Bartolo Luque, section Juegos Matemáticos of Investigación y Ciencia (that's the Spanish edition of Scientific American), Mayo 2021 Nº 536, if I remember well he refers in this article different kind of billiards.

Comment: **(Don't related to billiards)** I like the topics of the books *A View from the Top: Analysis, Combinatorics and Number Theory* by Alex Iosevich, Student Mathematical Library Vol. 39 of  American Mathematical Society (2007), and *Roots to Research: A Vertical Development of Mathematical Problems*, by Judith D. Sally and Paul J. Sally, Jr. , American Mathematical Society (2007), but I have not permission for the dissemination of the content of these books. The books don't seem to fit the requirements that you've claimed, I think that many undergraduated students can to understand the books.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds both quite fun! I'll check them out.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words @SeverinSchraven

Comment: I am so sorry, I just realized that I have never accepted your answer :(

Comment: There is not problem, very thanks much for your kind words professor @SeverinSchraven . I've edited from (this account) my profile user142929 on MathOverflow the posts about billiards with identifier and title, respectively, **429420** and *Arithmetic billiards, prime numbers and the Goldbach conjecture*, the post **424770** this *Novel examples, proofs or results in mathematics from arithmetic billiards* and my answer **431249** for the post with title *On equations with arithmetic functions*. I'm owner of other posts as  **423695** and **424501**. I evoke at my home possible applications.